# Two constructed triangles with common vertex have tangent circumcircles at this vertex.

Tags: triangles, circles, plane-geometry

[image]Here's a complicated-sounding geometry problem, Any help would be appreciated :)

Let $\triangle ABC$ be an obtuse-angled triangle with circumcentre $O$, circumcircle $\Gamma$ and $\angle ABC > 90^\circ$. Let $AB$ intersect the line through $C$ perpendicular to $AC$ in $D$. Let $l$ be the line through $D$ perpendicular to $AO$, and let $E$ be the intersection of $l$ and $AC$, and let $F$ be the point between $D$ and $E$ where $l$ intersects $\Gamma$. Can you prove that the circumcircles of triangles $\triangle BFE$ and $\triangle CFD$ are tangent at $F$?

Thanks :D

Comment: Well, I wasn't able to solve it and I have no more time today. So I'll list some simple observations which may or may not help anyone solving the problem. First, it seems that the centers of the two circles and $F$ are collinear on the line $AF$, proving this may be one possible approach to tackling the problem. Secondly, the triangles $\triangle  ABC$, $\triangle AED$ and $\triangle BEC$ are all similar. Finally, $A$, $C$, $D$ and the intersection of $l$ with $AO$ are all concyclic on the circle with diameter $AD$.

Comment: Woah, that's much further than I got. Thanks for the hints, now maybe I can get something going! :D Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Oh thanks for the edit, it looks cooler and simpler now. I haven't had a chance to look at it yet, but has anyone made any progress?

Answer (score 2):

Let $l$ intersect $AO$ at $H$, and $AO$ intersect the circle again at $P$. Since $AP$ is a diameter, $PC \perp AC$, so $P, C, D$ are collinear. Now the 2 altitudes $AC, DH$ of  $\triangle APD$ intersect at $E$, so $E$ is the orthocenter of $\triangle APD$. Thus $PE \perp AB$. Since $AP$ is a diameter, $PB \perp AB$, so $P, E, B$ are collinear.

$$\angle{PFE}=\angle{PFH}=90^{\circ}-\angle{HPF}=90^{\circ}-\angle{APF}=\angle{PBD}-\angle{DBF}=\angle{PBF}=\angle{EBF}$$

$$\angle{PFC}=\angle{PAC}=90^{\circ}-\angle{APC}=90^{\circ}-\angle{HPD}=\angle{HDP}=\angle{FDC}$$

Thus $PF$ is tangent to both the circumcircle of $\triangle BFE$ and the circumcircle of $\triangle CFD$, so the 2 circumcircles are tangent at $F$.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Hint: The diagram looks somewhat like this. You can solve the problem using simple geometry, I suppose.

Comment: Thanks for the diagram Inceptio. Could you please prove the question for me? To me the geometry isn't so simple :/ Thanks!

Comment: Well, I'm on to it. Will post the answer once done.

Comment: Hey Inceptio, not rushing you or pushing you or anything, but if it's fine with you, I kinda need the answer quite soon... Could you maybe post a solution quite soon? Thanks... :P

Comment: I'm trying it since then bro. I'm ain't really getting it. I got what to prove . But I'm not getting how to start it. -_-

Comment: @Inceptio Since this doesn't really answer the question, I recommend deleting the answer and editing the question to include the diagram instead. That way the question remains open and will attract more answers.

Comment: Sounds like a good plan. @Inceptio I'm sorry, I hope you're fine with helping me out. Take your time - I just need it for tomorrow. Thanks! :)

Comment: @ANerd Meanwhile, since this appears to be homework, it would be great if you could provide us with some more information. What attempts have you made at the problem? What machinery do you have access to? It wouldn't be much help if somebody provided a proof you cannot understand.

Comment: @EuYu Ah yes, I have tried firstly to draw the diagram but have failed miserably. I am not understanding anything so far (and what to do) but I have learnt some geometry at school (yep I'm still in grade school) so I could probably understand a proof given to me. I have a laptop if that's what you mean by machinery...

Comment: @ANerd By "machinery" I meant mathematical techniques, the theory you know and have access to. If by grade school you mean elementary school then wow, this problem is quite difficult.

Comment: @EuYu do you think maybe you can solve it? I know some circle geometry and cyclic quads but I don't think that's going to help much here. I'm in middle school, but I AM asian... You know, asian schools push their students a hell of a lot XD

Comment: @ANerd Well, I can give it a try. But I make no guarantees.

Comment: Thanks... I have faith in you ;) I'm sure you can do it!!

Comment: @EuYu Hey :) How's the problem going? I tried myself to prove it, but I'm just not seeing anything. I can visualize how the circumcircles of the triangles will actually be tangent... But proof eludes me

Comment: @Inceptio "You can solve the problem using simple geometry, I suppose." But most IMO geometry questions can be solved using "simple geometry". That doesn't necessarily mean that the question is easy to solve.

Comment: @IvanLoh: Sorry, sir. You train IMO team? Its a pleasure to be in contact with you.:)